# Finding eigenvalues of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, trace

Find all eigenvalues associated to the linear transformation $T \in L(\mathbb{K}^n)$ defined by $$T(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1 + \cdots + x_n, \ldots, x_1 + \cdots + x_n)$$
So, to find all eigenvalues one would normally only find the matrix associated to the linear transformation, and easily find the eigenvalues from there, right?
Well I have no idea how to "put" this linear transformation into matrix form.

Comment: Try to clarify the definition of $T$. What are $x_1+$ and $+x_n$?

Comment: I believe that there are a bit too many commas there

Comment: Yes, there were two commas that had no business being there. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I see how this is linear when you have that $c$ there. Doesn't this have $T(0,0,\dots,0)=(c,0,\dots,0) \neq (0,0,\dots,0)$?

Comment: @Ian This is a typo introduced by the latest edit (not by OP). I removed it. OP please check that it is correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation matrix of $T$ is
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\cdots1\\\hspace{-9 mm}\vdots&\hspace{-11 mm}\vdots\\1\cdots1}=\pmatrix{1\\\vdots\\1}\pmatrix{1\cdots1}=vv^T
$$
Then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=|\lambda I-A|=|\lambda I-vv^T|=\lambda^n-Tr(vv^T)\lambda^{n-1}=\lambda^n-n\lambda^{n-1}=\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-n)
$$
for $vv^T$ is a Rank-$1$ matrix and all principal minors above $2$ are $0$.

Thus  of $A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$ with its multiplicity of $n-1$ and $n$ with the multiplicity of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $e_i$ the $i$-th vector of the standard basis $\cal E$. Then
$$
T(e_i)=(1,...,1)=e_1+\cdots +e_n
$$
for all $i=1,...,n$. Thus the matrix associated to $T$ with respect to the basis $\cal E$ is the matrix which has $1$ in every place.

Comment: So, the only eigenvalue would be 1, with  mulitplicity _n_? Can one assume that?

Comment: Not till you convince yourself that the characteristic polynomial of that matrix is $(1-\lambda)^n$.

Comment: HINT: clearly it is **not**

Comment: HINT#2: Ask yourself what the rank of that matrix is, and when you have answered that, ask yourself what the dimension of $\ker(T)$ is.

Comment: So, the the rank would be 1 and the dimension of ker(T) is n-1?

Comment: @SharkFin : Right. So now you know the eigenvectors and their multiplicities, don't you?